# Formula for the projection of a space curve drawn on a surface onto a tangent plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I could not understand why the following space curve vector formula holds.

$$ p(s) = q(s) + (p(s) \cdot e) e $$

The conditions are as follows

$$ p(s) = p(u(s),v(s)) $$

$q (s)$ is the plane curve obtained by orthogonal projection of $p (s)$ onto the tangent plane of the curved surface at $p_0$ where $e$ is the unit vector at $p_0$ on the surface.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOQbh.jpg)

Comment: Please, replace "explanatory surface" by "tangent plane"

Comment: thank you for reply. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us re-write relationship

$$p(s) = q(s) + (p(s) \cdot e) e$$

with matrix notations, the uppercase letters being the column vectors associated with their lowercase correspondent, using the fact that point "$.$" denotes a dot product :

$$P=Q+(E^TP)E$$

($T$ means "transpose"), itself equivalent (because we have a number inside parentheses) to

$$P=Q+E(E^TP) \ \iff \ P=Q+(EE^T)P  \ \iff \ (I-EE^T)P=Q$$

where we recognize in $(I-EE^T)$ a way to write orthogonal projection operator on the tangent plane (more generally the hyperplane) with normal vector $E$.
See a proof in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2268192) I gave some years ago.